# Drupal7: How to add the alt and title attribute to an image by code

Tags: media

I am using the file_create_url() function to create the URL for images.
The code is:

```
<img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_history_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>">
```

But I just noticed that the alt and title attributes are not added to the HTML output, eventhough I added them for the image in the admin.

How would I change the above code, so that it adds the *alt* and *title* attributes if they are filled in the Admin interface. Or what other function should I use?

Thanks.

Boutros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to my own question:

```
 <?php print render ($content['field_history_image']); ?>
```

The above code, prints the image (the URL and the alt and title attributes if they exist).
It does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are rendering a field , you can use below code

```
<?php
$image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_history_image');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_history_image', $image[0]);
print render($output);
?>
```

OR

```
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_history_image');
print render($view);
```